# django admin ツールの表示が開発モードとプロダクションモードで異なる

Tags: django

### 前提

django admin tool についてです。

---

### 発生している問題

django admin tool を開発モードで実行すると `search.svg` が表示されます。
しかしプロダクションモードだと表示されません。

開発モードだと追加の＋、削除のーが表示されます。
しかしプロダクションモードだと表示されません。

次は実施済みです。

```sh
python -m pip install mod_wsgi
pyhon manage.py collectstatic
```

---

### 補足情報 (OS, ツールのバージョンなど)

- Python 3.6.1 (64 bit)
- Django 1.11.3
- Windows 7

Comment: とりあえず回答できると思われますので再オープン票を投じましたが、タイトルも変更いただけませんか？

Comment: タイトルを日本語に変更しました。